# Pytorch : Pass from grid to image coordinate convention for use of grid_sample

Tags: python, image, pytorch, reshape

I need to interpolate some deformation grid in PyTorch and decided to use the function `grid_sample` [(see doc)](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.grid_sample). I need to reshape grids as images back and forth with theses conventions :

- `N` Batch size
- `D` grid depth (for 3D images)
- `H` grid height
- `W` grid width
- `d` grid dimension (=2 or 3)

images format is `(N,2,H,W)` in 2D (resp. `(N,3,D,H,W)` in 3D)
when grid format is `(N,H,W,2)` (resp. `(N,D,H,W,3)`in 3D)

I can't use `reshape` or `view` because they do not arrange the data as I wish. I need to have (for example)

```
grid_in_grid_convention[0,:,:,0] == grid_in_image_convention[0,0,:,:]
```

I came up with theses functions to make the reshaping which works fine but I am sure that there is a more compact/fast way to do so. What are your taught ?

```py
def grid2im(grid):
    """Reshape a grid tensor into an image tensor
        2D  [T,H,W,2] -> [T,2,H,W]
        3D  [T,D,H,W,2] -> [T,D,H,W,3]
    """
    if grid.shape[0] == 1 and grid.shape[-1] == 2: # 2D case, batch =1
        return torch.stack((grid[0,:,:,0],grid[0,:,:,1]),dim = 0).unsqueeze(0)

    elif grid.shape[0] == 1 and grid.shape[-1] == 3: # 3D case, batch =1 
        return torch.stack((grid[0,:,:,:,0],grid[0,:,:,:,1],grid[0,:,:,:,2]),
                            dim = 0).unsqueeze(0)
    
    elif grid.shape[-1] == 2:
        N,H,W,d = grid.shape
        temp = torch.zeros((N,H,W,d))
        for n in range(N):
            temp[n,:,:,:] = torch.stack((grid[n,:,:,0],grid[n,:,:,1]),dim = 0).unsqueeze(0)
        return temp
    
    elif grid.shape[-1] == 3:
        N,D,H,W,d =grid.shape
        temp = torch.zeros((N,D,H,W,d))
        for n in range(N):
            temp[n,:,:,:,:] = torch.stack((grid[n,:,:,:,0],
                                           grid[n,:,:,:,1],
                                           grid[n,:,:,:,2]),
                            dim = 0).unsqueeze(0)
    else:
        raise ValueError("input argument expected is [N,H,W,2] or [N,D,H,W,3]",
                         "got "+str(grid.shape)+" instead.")
```

```py
def im2grid(image):
    """Reshape an image tensor into a grid tensor
        2D case [T,2,H,W]   ->  [T,H,W,2]
        3D case [T,3,D,H,W] ->  [T,D,H,W,3]
    """
    # No batch 
    if image.shape[0:2] == (1,2):
        return torch.stack((image[0,0,:,:],image[0,1,:,:]),dim= 2).unsqueeze(0)
    elif image.shape[0:2] == (1,3):
        return torch.stack((image[0,0,:,:],image[0,1,:,:],image[0,2,:,:]),
                           dim = 2).unsqueeze(0)
    # Batch size > 1
    elif image.shape[0] > 0 and image.shape[1] == 2 :
        N,d,H,W = image.shape
        temp = torch.zeros((N,H,W,d))
        for n in range(N):
            temp[n,:,:,:] = torch.stack((image[n,0,:,:],image[n,1,:,:]),dim= 2).unsqueeze(0)
        return temp
    elif image.shape[0] > 0 and image.shape[1] == 3 :
        N,d,D,H,W = image.shape
        temp = torch.zeros((N,D,H,W,d))
        for n in range(N):
            temp[n,:,:,:] = torch.stack((image[n,0,:,:],
                                         image[n,1,:,:],
                                         image[n,2,:,:]),
                           dim = 2).unsqueeze(0)
        return temp
    else:
        raise ValueError("input argument expected is [1,2,H,W] or [1,3,D,H,W]",
                         "got "+str(image.shape)+" instead.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`transpose()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html#torch.transpose). For example, if you want `[T,H,W,2] -> [T,2,H,W]` for a tensor, say `grid`, you can do

```
grid = grid.transpose(2,3).transpose(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ihdv answer is correct. Thank you !

I complete here the answer with the two functions above corrected in a way more efficient and elegant way.

```py
def grid2im(grid):
    """Reshape a grid tensor into an image tensor
        2D  [T,H,W,2] -> [T,2,H,W]
        3D  [T,D,H,W,2] -> [T,D,H,W,3]
    """
    if grid.shape[-1] == 2: # 2D case
        return grid.transpose(2,3).transpose(1,2)

    elif grid.shape[-1] == 3: # 3D case
        return grid.transpose(3,4).transpose(2,3).transpose(1,2)
    else:
        raise ValueError("input argument expected is [N,H,W,2] or [N,D,H,W,3]",
                         "got "+str(grid.shape)+" instead.")



def im2grid(image):
    """Reshape an image tensor into a grid tensor
        2D case [T,2,H,W]   ->  [T,H,W,2]
        3D case [T,3,D,H,W] ->  [T,D,H,W,3]
    """
    # No batch
    if image.shape[1] == 2:
        return image.transpose(1,2).transpose(2,3)
    elif image.shape[1] == 3:
        return image.transpose(1,2).transpose(2,3).transpose(3,4)
    else:
        raise ValueError("input argument expected is [1,2,H,W] or [1,3,D,H,W]",
                         "got "+str(image.shape)+" instead.")
```